# ToolbarItem isEnabled property is available in xaml, not code

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a form where a user can enter some data and save it to a database. I have been trying to add basic validation, making a user have to enter a value in every field. I want my save button to be unavailable until the user has entered some information in every form.

Here is my button:

```
<ToolbarItem Name="MenuItem1" Order="Primary" Text="Save" Priority="1" Command="{Binding SaveDataCommand}" IsEnabled="{Binding CanSaveData}"/>
```

I can access the `isEnabled` property in the XAML but where this gets infuriating is that I can't then reupdate this property. The button gets stuck in whatever state I tell it on load. I have checked my view model and it is returning a boolean which is correct (printing it to the console), it's just there is no way of updating the button state.

I even tried adding a new button that would force update the enabled state however this wouldn't work

```
<ToolbarItem x:Name="whyxamarinwhy" Name="MenuItem1" Order="Primary" Text="Save" Priority="1" Command="{Binding SaveEvent}" IsEnabled="{Binding CanCreateEvent}"/>

whyxamarinwhy.isenabled = true; //I cannot access this property because it doesn't exist.
```

Is the only way to implement this functionality going to be using a custom renderer?

Comment: I don't know what's happening here, but to me, it doesn't appear even on XAML. According to [Microsoft docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.MenuItem/) this property is for internal use of XF platform. Despite this, you can handle the user ability to trigger the action thru the `CanExecute` command's delegate instead of enabling/disabling the button itself.

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza how would I go about doing this, would you be able to post an answer? I can see the methods to call however I can't seem to interact with them in anyway `SaveData.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();` or `SaveEvent.CanExecute();`

Comment: @SushiHangover has already done it. It's perfect =)

Answer (score 3):

> MenuItem.IsEnabledProperty / For internal use by the Xamarin.Forms platform.

You should use the `Command`'s `CanExecute` of the `ToolbarItem` to determine if the `Execute` method can be triggered.

Since you are already binding the command to `SaveDataCommand`, you can toggle the return of the `CanExecute` of that command to determine if the menu item button should be allowed to trigger the attached command.

You did not post your ViewModel, but in a inner-class `ICommand` implementation, something as simple as this works:

```
static bool SaveDataCommandCanExecute = true;
class SaveDataCommand : ICommand
{
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        // your code needs to toggle SaveDataCommandCanExecute to determine if the Execute method can be triggered
        return SaveDataCommandCanExecute;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Or even use the XF implementation of it (Xamarin.Forms.Command). Like `Command SaveCommand = new Command(YourExecuteSaveMethod, YourCanExecuteMethod);` and on every property that affects the 'can execute' state you also call ` SaveCommand.ChangeCanExecute();`

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza true, for some reason I always think of the `ICommand` first... ;-)

Comment: It's the `warrior way`! And it fits perfectly too.

Comment: Works for enabling/disabling the event (but that was never my issue), I found the issue was with my databinding, not raising that the value had changed (I'm new to mvvm and its never explained well). 

I've actually managed to get the button enabling/disabling, not bothered if xamarin don't want me using the `IsEnabled` property, they give I use :)